# Why doesn't my overloaded comma operator get called?

Tags: c++, gcc, operator-overloading, comma-operator

I'm trying to overload the comma operator with a non-friend non-member function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class comma_op
{
    int val;

public:
    void operator,(const float &rhs)
    {
        cout << this->val << ", " << rhs << endl;
    }
};

void operator,(const float &lhs, const comma_op &rhs)
{
    cout << "Reached!\n";      // this gets printed though
    rhs, lhs;                  // reversing this leads to a infinite recursion ;)
}

int main()
{
    comma_op obj;
    12.5f, obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the comma operator usable from both sides, with a float. Having a member function only allows me to write `obj, float_val`, while having an additional helper non-friend non-member function allows me to write `float_val, obj`; but the member operator function doesn't get called.

GCC cries:

```
comma.cpp: In function ‘void operator,(const float&, const comma_op&)’:
comma.cpp:19: warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect
comma.cpp:19: warning: right-hand operand of comma has no effect
```

**Note:**
I realise that overloading operators, that too to overload comma op., Is confusing and is not at all advisable from a purist's viewpoint. I'm just learning C++ nuances here.

Comment: As a point of style, I think it is generally considered to be unwise to redefine the meaning of the operators as that leads to difficult to maintain code: is a * b doing a multiplication or has it been redefined as a vector cross product? (Some would say that one's OK.)

Comment: @Skizz: I guess you've missed noticing, what I've mentioned in the _Note_ right from the beginning of this post.

Comment: and comma overloading is often especially problematic because of its low precedence

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
void operator,(const float &rhs)
```

You need a `const` here.

```
void operator,(const float &rhs) const {
    cout << this->val << ", " << rhs << endl;
}
```

The reason is because

```
rhs, lhs
```

will call

```
rhs.operator,(lhs)
```

Since `rhs` is a `const comma_op&`, the method must be a `const` method. But you only provide a non-`const` `operator,`, so the default definition will be used.